# Kernel panic - not syncing:VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown block(2,0)

Tags: centos, kernel, boot, gentoo

I have the same **Gentoo** version installed on 16 machines. Using the same 3 DVDs created in the same way with the same **CentOS** version and 2 same brand portable DVD-ROMs, I have managed to get the installation on 15 of them. The 16th is showing up this error `Kernel panic - not syncing:VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown block(2,0)` after selecting boot from the DVD in the bios boot menu and booting up until I select the install option. Once the option is selected, the error message appears. I wanted to know if there is an error guide for the `unknown block` numbers or would like to find the root cause for this.

There is no difference between the machines' BIOS versions, but I don't know how the first **Gentoo** install was performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It somehow appears that the machine didn't like the DVD format. When presented with a FAT32 formatted USB stick, everything worked just fine. Can't explain why this happened though, since nothing was different from the other machines.

Answer (score 0):

Check the cables are HDD on 16th machine connected the same way ? Are the HDD partitioned the same way? Also check RAM as installation CD is likely to use RAMFS during installation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, as far as I've seen in df -kh / lsblk -fl the disks should be the same.